# Problems with linux mint boot

Tags: linux-mint, boot, system-installation, boot-loader

I had already this problem with sparkylinux. Trying to install this other distribution I broke windows, so now I'm trying to install Linux Mint using a USB.
It all works but when the installation ends and I reboot the system, it reboots into the USB live installation.

Comment: maybe you forgot to remove the flash drive from the USB port

Comment: When should I remove it. Before rebooting, before the installation or whatever?

Comment: Ok. But. If During the boot I press F10, so I can see all the bootable things, there's only the usb (even after the installation on the hard drive). If I remove the usb it says "No Bootable Device Found".

Comment: then your issue is not a problem with rebooting into the live system ...... the problem is that the hard drive does not have a bootable system after the linux install .... that is either a hardware failure or incorrect install options

Comment: I think so, but what can I do

Comment: do the research about the actual problem  ...... searching for `reboots into the USB live installation` will not give you any useful  results ......... `hard drive unbootable after linux install` should yield useful results   .............. i think that  you may not be following the install instructions carefully

Comment: I'll try to search online a solution

Comment: find an online step by step installation tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by going in bios mode, turning secure boot on, going to security, add certigied uefi, and selected shimx.efi (or something similar) and then save.